# I see deleted records in Spring with JDBC

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc

I have a webapp with Spring. I connect to the DB via JDBC. My issue comes in the following workflow:

1. I insert some testing record to the DB with the app. I see in the app and in SQLDeveloper (same query) that the record gets inserted. No problem.
2. I delete that record from SQLDeveloper. I see in SQLDeveloper that the record gets deleted. No problem
3. I go back to the webapp and refresh the page. **Problem**: the deleted records are still there!.

I'm sure I'm using the same query in the app and in SQLDeveloper (this is the only instance when I don't see the same in both environments). I tried restarting the app, but I can't imagine what else to do. Is there any cache system in Spring that could be causing this?

I can post some code if it would be any help, though I doubt it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you haven't committed the result of your deletion in SQLDeveloper, so you see your deletion in SQLDeveloper (same transaction), but not anywhere else, because those are running in different transactions.

EDIT: To commit, you can just execute the command `commit;` in SQLDeveloper, or hit the commit button at the top of the query window (a DB icon with a green tick in front of it)

Comment: So right! I just assumed it was a Spring problem, I didn't even think about the transaction... Thank you!